# Tokenization and Authentication in Power Apps

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerapps, powerbi-embedded

I have built some reports on PowerBI and embedded it on Power Apps. There is a summary page which has 4 different visuals (power BI pages) embedded. Its like page divided into 4 different tiles with 4 different powerbi visuals. When I log into power apps it asks to sign-in.

Earlier, when I click on any 1 of the sign in button, it refreshes entire summary page and visuals from all 4 tiles were displayed. Now something happened and it requires authentication for all 4 tiles.

Can anyone help me what should be the solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using single iFrame or multiple iFrame's for embedding different visuals from your Power BI Report?